# Find all roots with multiplicities of $x^3+x^2+2x-1\equiv 0\pmod 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that the roots are $x\equiv 1,2\pmod 3$, but I found this using brute force. How would I find it using number theory?

Comment: Well you still haven't found their multiplicities, but in general over a finite field it's not a bad idea to just test every element to find roots. In this case there are only $3$ possible roots anyway.

Comment: By $\rm\color{#c00}{Fermat}$  $\,\color{#c00}{x^3-x}+x^2-1\equiv x^2-1\, $ has roots $\:\!\pm1.\,$ By Vieta the roots $\,1,-1,r\,$ have sum $\,r = -1\ $ (minus coef of $\,x^2).\, $  It's overkill to seek deeper methods for such a simple problem (tiny modulus).  $\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do is factor the polynomial. Once you have found, for example, that $1$ is a root, you know that $x-1\equiv x+2$ is a factor. Using long division or otherwise, you get
$$x^3+x^2+2x-1\equiv (x+2)(x^2+2x+1).$$
Now factor $x^2+2x+1$ to find the other two roots (counting multiplicities).

Comment: The factorization can be discovered like this:  $x^3+x^2+2x-1 \equiv x^3+x^2-x-1 \equiv x^2(x+1)-(x+1)$